# How to run yarn develop for strapi when there is problem with memory?

Tags: mysql, yarnpkg, strapi

So I have an issue running yarn develop in my VS Code. The issue is this:

```
 {code: 'ER_OUT_OF_SORTMEMORY', errno: 1038, sqlMessage: 'Out of sort memory, consider increasing server sort buffer size', sqlState: 'HY001', index: 0, sql: 'select * from `strapi_database_schema` order by `time` DESC limit 1'}
```

So they said I must increase sort_buffer_size in my.ini file to 8M which I managed to. But after I restart MySQL server after the change and try to run yarn develop again, it still shows the same error of out of sort memory. It seems that after I changed my.ini, it is not reflected in the schema I am working on in MySQL workbench to get strapi to run. Is there any solution to this?

I also checked the error log and there is no error in the MySQL server as well.